# Azure function debug checkpoint for event hub trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How to specify checkpoint when debug function locally in visual studio 2017?  I don’t want to receive all the old messages

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible today - the checkpointing occurs in the storage account, so as long as you are connected to a storage account that has processed to a specific point, re-running will start from the checkpoint.  There is a feature request to change that you can track here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1240